# Why is sample mean talked about when the sample is not a random variable?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable

(This question can be considered a follow-up to the following question - [About Sampling and Random Variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368492/about-sampling-and-random-variables#))

I am taking a statistics course and every resource I look at says the following - let X be a random variable with $E(X)=\mu$, and $s_1$, $s_2$, ..., $s_n$ be $n$ samples drawn from X. The sample mean is defined to be $\bar{s}=(s_1+s_2+...+s_n)/n$. Then $E(\bar{s})=\mu$ and $\bar{s}$ is an unbiased estimator. The question is - since $\bar{s}$ is NOT a random variable (see link above), how can its expectation be talked about?

Comment: I do not get the point: $\bar s$ is a random variable.

Comment: Apparently not. I think they consider $\bar{s}$ the fixed value obtained post sampling, and thus do not treat it as a random variable. I agree though that it makes $\bar{s}$ meaningless, if $\bar{S}$ is the only object you can reason about.

Answer (score 1):

I think your understanding of the issue might be helped by reviewing the difference between an *estimate* and and *estimator*, as well as perhaps some more careful notation.

Suppose $S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_n$ are IID random variables with the same distribution as $X$ and $E(X) = \mu$. Then the mean of these random variables is
$$ \bar{S} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n S_i.$$

Now $E(\bar{S}) =  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n E(S_i) = \mu $.

We call $\bar{S}$ an *estimator*; it is a random variable and therefore has a probability distribution. This distribution has mean $\mu$.

Now suppose I observe data $(s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n)$. This has mean $$\bar{s} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n s_i.$$
$\bar{s}$ is an *estimate* of $\mu$. It is a realisation of the estimator $\bar{S}$, in the same way that each $s_i$ is a realisation of the random variable $S_i$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Why is $\bar{s}$ then even meaningful at all? And why is it even talked about? Since the only object that can be reasoned about is $\bar{S}$, the estimate $\bar{s}$ is entirely meaningless.

Comment: $\bar{s}$ is the thing we actually observe, it is a summary of the data.  It tells us about the population mean of $\bar{S}$ and $X$.  It is not meaningless at all

Comment: What I mean is, $\bar{S}$ can be reasoned about, you can find $E(\bar{S})$ or higher moments, $E(f(\bar{S}))$ for some function f, or $Pr(\bar{S}>\alpha)$, and so on. But all you can say about $\bar{s}$ is that it is a real number. Thats it. Any more reasoning cannot be continued without appealing to $\bar{S}$, for it is simply a deterministic number. If you try to reason where that number came from or anything else, you go back to $\bar{S}$. The value $\bar{s}$ indeed seems meaningless without any concrete application.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in [About Sampling and Random Variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368492/about-sampling-and-random-variables#), "You can think of a "population" as an infinite reservoir of values drawn from $Y$. Sampling from a population is analogous to repeatedly drawing new values from $Y$. A sample of size $N$ is a size-$N$ collection of individual draws from $Y$." Moreover, "If you flip one coin $N$ times, that is the same as flipping $N$ identical coins, once per coin."

A *random sample* is like $N$ identical coins, it is a *set of independent and identically distributed random variables*, $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_N$. Their mean $\overline{X}_N$*is* a random variable end its expected value is $E[\overline{X}_N]=E[X_1]=\mu$.

An *observed* random sample is a set of observed values (let's say, the heads and tails you get when you flip $N$ identical coins), and the *observed* sample mean is the *realization* of the sample mean random variable.